# why {locale} in laravel 8 duplicate in the link?

Tags: laravel, localization

There is a problem in browsing the website on Localization in Laravel 8. When I access a tab from the first time it works fine, but when I try to navigate to another tab I see a duplicated in the link.

Example:
for the first place the link shows like this-> website/{locale}/issues
when I try to navigate to other tab, the links show like this -> website/{locale}/{locale}/issues
then 404 not found error appears.

Route web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomePageController::class, 'index'])->middleware('setLocale');
    Route::get('/issues', [App\Http\Controllers\HomePageController::class, 'allIssues'])->middleware('setLocale');
    Route::get('/dialogues', [App\Http\Controllers\HomePageController::class, 'allDialogues'])->middleware('setLocale');
});
```

nav.blade.php

```
<li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link" href="{{app()->getLocale()}}/issues">@lang('auth.issues-nav-tab')</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link" href="{{app()->getLocale()}}/dialogues">@lang('auth.dialogues-nav-tab'</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by with this setps :

```php
Route::group([
  'prefix' => '{locale}', 
  'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], //check 2 character i.e en,fr,mm,etc..
  'middleware' => 'setlocale'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomePageController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/issues', [App\Http\Controllers\HomePageController::class, 'allIssues'])->name('issues');
    Route::get('/dialogues', [App\Http\Controllers\HomePageController::class, 'allDialogues'])->name('dialogues');
});
```

In blade :

```php
href="{{ route('issues', app()->getLocale()) }}"
```

In middleware :

```php
class SetLocale
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked fine. I also added '/' at the start of each links.